# how would you provide menu written in different (locale) languages instead of repeating them in every page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu

below is an example of menu in french, I will also have it in another five more languages:

```
<a href="/<%= @lang %>/">Jeux</a>
<a href="/<%= @lang %>/get-the-player">Obtenir le lecteur</a>
<a href="/<%= @lang %>/about">À propos</a>
<a href="/<%= @lang %>/faq">FAQ</a>
<a href="/<%= @lang %>/contact">Contact</a>
```

at the moment the menu are in a relevant pages (.html.erb), by using the code listed below

```
<%= content_for :menu do %>    
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/">Jeux</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/get-the-player">Obtenir le lecteur</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/about">À propos</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/faq">FAQ</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/contact">Contact</a>
<% end %>
```

once I have done above I have got the reference on the application.html.erb

```
<%= yield :menu %>
```

it can be done exactly the same way for other languages, however, is there a way where I could avoid the repetition of the code. perhaps makes the controller to go and find for it and render it in exact place ? Help please,

thanks in advance!

===========================================================================

```
    **CHECK BELOW FOR SOLUTIONS THAT I HAVE PROVIDED**
```

Comment: Are you using I18n to translate your application?

Comment: nop I am not using translate, at the moment all of the pages are static that's how the specs has defined it.

Comment: Okay so see Padde's post for the i18n API, its the best and easiest way to translate your application ;)

Comment: I have got the sample working for that, but any solutions you could offer that could be done via a controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the built in [internationalization (i18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Edit: Another way is to use localized views, as described [in the ruby on rails i18n guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views). For example, you could name your files `index.fr.html.erb` and `index.en.html.erb`. Then, depending on your `I18n.locale` settings, the appropriate view is rendered.

Comment: I have got a sample working for that! but any other solutions ?

Comment: Why would you want to use somerhing else? The i18n API is well tested, maintainable, extendable and as easy as it gets.

Comment: thank you very much for you effort, currently I am editing quite a large site, your input is much appreciated.

Comment: **@padde** in the end I have utilized internationalization API, much easier :)

Comment: **@padde** if possible could you help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310812/set-locale-automatically-in-ruby-on-rails) please?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of this to do on your site, I suggest you take a look at Google Closure Templates (Soy). It has a localization framework that you can use to accomplish that.

If you use it then you write a Soy template to generate the menus and (other parts of the site) and use the localization capabilities to display the appropriate language for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is what needs to be done. On my _header.html.erb (or application.html.erb depending on how you have done it), I have created an if statement like this listed below:

```
<% if params[:lang]=="es" %>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/">Jeux</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/get-the-player">Obtenir le lecteur</a>
    ..........
    ..........
<% end %>


<% if params[:lang]=="en" %>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/">Games</a>
    <a href="/<%= @lang %>/get-the-player">Get the Player</a>
    ..........
    ..........
<% end %>
```

By this you can manipulate to have more if I/you wish. Yes Guys you could do this with internationalization API, however this time I am editing a big application which could kill more time plus makes it less productive. So The above source code could be an alternative way. :). Thank You guys for all your input on this one.

Comment: you (or another developer) will be thankful, when he dives into the code in a year or so, and finds that your application sticks to the standards instead of trying to re-invent the wheel. Using i18n is easy. And above all: it's maintainable.

Comment: What if you decided to add a `class` attribute to your `a` tags? You would have to do this stupid thing for _every single language_ over and over again.

Comment: If you really don't want to use the i18n api, then at least split the different laguages into separate files and name them `_header.es.html`, `_header.fr.html`, and so on. Rails will figure out the rest for you.

Comment: Oh and please do not extend your question inside an answer, place additional info below your original question and mark it as edit.

Comment: i already have class attribute for them, i just did not decide to post them here, not relevant! I do not really see a point of splitting it into different headers. Also I implemented 'i18ni' but the base_page processor that i have under the page_processor controller did not react to different locale (a whole lot of different mess there). I know it is easier to implement il8n and rightly so I have implemented for another application. but at this time I do no really have time :( to work around it.

Comment: also can you direct me to any examples of native ruby running on AWS Elastic Bean stalk as AWS seems to support native ruby ??

Comment: Why would you even store the same value in `params[:lang]` and `@lang`? This is bad style.

Comment: Sorry, i have no experience with AWS, i always use Heroku.

Comment: Ok, how do you set the language in the first place?

Comment: by default the site should go to lang='en', so in index method/action @lang=en is declared. But this will be changed to where header would automatically decide which locale it is. look at this website antixgames.com  this is project i am working on ;).

Comment: if you wish you could download the AGP plugins on your mobile or in your pc to play any game, unlimited trail !

Comment: @padde in the end I have utilized internationalization API, much easier :)